# Insert image from JSON objet into handlebars template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to iterate over a movie object and insert a movie poster into the dom. Example of one of the objects I get back:

```
Object
   actors:          "Ryan Reynolds"
   created_at:      "2016-04-03T16:15:53.623Z"
   creator_id:       1
  poster: Object
    thumb: Object
      url:          "/uploads/movie/poster/2/thumb_a_deadpool.jpg"
    url:            "/uploads/movie/poster/2/a_deadpool.jpg"
```

I iterate over the movie collection here:

```
let api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/movies' 

fetch(api_url).then(function(resp) {
  resp.json().then(function(movies) {
    console.log(movies)
    let tmpl = Handlebars.compile(eachMovietmpl)
      for (let movie of movies) {
        let moviePoster = $('#movie_poster').html(movie["poster"]["thumb"].url)
        let title = $('#movie_title_main_page').html(movie.title)
        let html = tmpl(movie)
        $('#now_playing_section').append(html)
      }
  })
})
```

The line:

```
let title = $('#movie_title_main_page').html(movie.title)
```

works fine as each movie title gets inserted into dom in the appropriate element. When I try doing the same thing with the poster I only get one url back that gets inserted into the dom. Doesn't seem to be iterating over the movie posters. I've also tried

```
let moviePoster = $('#movie_poster').html(movie.poster.thumb.url)
```

which also does nothing. Here is the handlebars template:

```
<div id="movie_poster_wrapper">
  <p id="movie_title_main_page">{{title}}</p>
  <p id="movie_poster"><img src="{{moviePoster}}"></p>
  <p id="movie_poster_release">{{movieRelease}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the whitesapce in Json so that it can be easily read.

Comment: try console log after getting the poster url 
i check it out it works fine with me. 
i thnk something is wrong with the ids u r using check that out

Comment: The id's appear to be fine. So I made some progress and I'm able to get an image into the dom by replacing the 'moviePoster' variable with 'let moviePoster = $('#movie_poster').children('img').attr('src', movie.poster.thumb.url)', The only problem is i'm still not able to iterate over the collection properly. I only get one image back.

Comment: You mean to say that you are still getting the  one image in console or in template ????

Comment: you have to use some kind of loop in template handler..
`{{#each }}
      
{{/each }}`

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying the loop helper you mentioned but nothing so far. I will post the solution to this problem when I find it.